# Is there an alternative to "background-position" to have support in Gmail?

Tags: css, gmail, background-image, background-position

According to [this CSS guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), Gmail, does not support `background-position`, `left`, `right`, and other CSS properties.

I have a div with background and I want to put this image on right of that div.

Here is my HTML -

```
 <div style="background-image: url('pic.jpg'); background-position:right; background-repeat: no-repeat;" dir="rtl">
```

As Gmail doesn't support the `background-position` I'm not getting the desired output.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Too vague. What do you actually need to do?

Comment: I have a background image in a div, I want to put It on right of div. by default It's on left.

Comment: bg images are pretty unreliable in emails. If you don't need text over it, us an inline image. If you do, place the text in the image. HTML sucks, and that's just how it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use short hand method. It will let you use **background position** in Gmail.

```
background: url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat left;
```